# Static loop variable in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, loops, variables, scope

I may using a misnomer here. I would like a variable to be set just once, at the first iteration of a loop, and retain its' value from previous iterations.
For example, I set variable value to 0, if unset. Then, based on the iteration logic, the value can change, and in the next iteration it will show the value from the previous iteration.
Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i dont understant the question, bud you can set the variable before the loop and after then you can modify the value inside.
If you set "*var*" outside the loop you can modify and use it in all loops.

```
var, run = nil, true
while run
  var = 1 unless var
  puts "IN: #{var}"

  if var > 1
    run = false
    break
  end

  var += 1
end
puts "OUT: #{var}"

# => IN: 1
# => IN: 2
# => OUT: 2
```

Maybe this? You can use Proc.new, but it's same line before.

```
process = Proc.new{|var|
  var = 0 unless var # first set if nil
  puts "IN: #{var}"
  var
}

run, i = true, 0
while run
  var = process.call(var)
  puts "After process: #{var}"
  break unless run = ( i < 2 )
  var += 1 # logic modify
  i += 1
end

puts "OUT: #{var}"

# => [true, 0]
# => IN: 0
# => After process: 0
# => IN: 1
# => After process: 1
# => IN: 2
# => After process: 2
# => OUT: 2
```

Comment: Hi Lukas. That is what I know. I was wondering if there is a way within the loop. I have thought that I have read somewhere of a way to do this within the loop, and keep it just within the scope of the loop. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @user1134991 I don't know, but this may help. Or you can use instance variable, but i dont find information about this problem. So maybe its not "easy" way to do it.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about the scope? It's a loop. If you declare something inside of it, that's where it gets scoped, and that may reset each iteration depending on the construct used. By putting it outside the loop you're declaring your intent for it to persist between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of not doing what you want.

```
b = binding
3.times do |i|
  eval("foo = (foo.nil?) ? 10 : (foo+1)", b)
  eval("p foo", b)
  p binding
end
```

The fundamental reason it won't work like you want is because Ruby creates a new binding for each pass through the loop. I can't think of any trickery around that except to use an external binding as an anchor point. I use the eval interface to the external binding only for illustration. The right way to do the same thing is to just declare a variable outside the loop, as you already know.

```
10
#<Binding:0x00000001708f40>
11
#<Binding:0x000000017089a0>
12
#<Binding:0x00000001708428>
```

Comment: Why would you need `eval` for something like this? A closure can do the job. This is like using a jackhammer to drive in a nail.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it's the right way to do it. I was trying to illustrate that the new bindings for every loop iteration is the fundamental limitation. And at the same time show that using an external static binding "solves" the problem. Yes, of course there are better ways to attach to the external binding. It's just that eval allows an explicit attachment for showing what I mean.

Comment: Given that the question revolves around ways of avoiding having to declare things outside the loop, this fails that test as well. It's an interesting approach, but so crazy there's now way this should show up in production code.

Comment: Perhaps my reply broke the rules of StackOverflow in that it wasn't meant to be a solution. It was meant to show that a solution doesn't exist.

Comment: It's okay to post an answer of that sort. I just think this sends people down a dangerous path if they follow your advice.